# Facebook app : how can user login with new facebook app same as old facebook app

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created 2 Facebook apps, one is old app, other one is new facebook app.

They works both, but i want to all which user are login on old app.that user can  be able to login on new app, it is possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login cannot be moved over to another App. Users need to authorize the new App again. You can use the Business Mapping api to identify users between two Apps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business